# Как передать List<int> как параметр из C# в C++ CLI?

Tags: c#, c++-cli

Ну собственно в заголовке и есть вопрос.

У меня есть репозиторий c# который хранит `List<int>` нужно все это дело передать в c++ CLI

Как это сделать?

**Правка**

Я использую CLI как адаптер для чистой C++ имплементации.
Я передаю из C# `List` в CLI , CLI его получает конвертирует в `vector` и вызывает метод из чистого `C++` класса. Который естественно ничего не знает о `List` и знает только как работать с `vector`

**Правка**

Вот так выглядит функция в C++ которую нужно вызвать из CLI

```
int computeMulPlusVals(std::vector<int> const & vect_first, std::vector<int> 
const & vect_second)
{
int result = 0;

int firstVectSize = vect_first.size();
int secondVectSize = vect_second.size();

int size = std::min(firstVectSize, secondVectSize);

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
{
    result += vect_first[i] * vect_second[i];
}

return result;
}
```

Вот функция в CLI

```
int MathCore_CLI::computeMulPlusVals(List<int>^ list_first, List<int>^ list_second)
{
    auto vec_first = std::vector<int>(list_first->Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < list_first->Count; i++)
    {
        vec_first.at(i) = list_first[i];
    }

    auto vec_second = std::vector<int>(list_second->Count);

    for (int i = 0; i < list_second->Count; i++)
    {
        vec_second.at(i) = list_second[i];
    }

    return m_pMathCore->computeMulPlusVals(vec_first, vec_second);
}
```

получаю вот такую ошибку

> Severity   Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
>   Error   LNK2028 unresolved token (0A0003A5) "public: int __cdecl MathCore::computeMulPlusVals(class std::vector > const &,class std::vector > const &)" (?computeMulPlusVals@MathCore@@$$FQEAAHAEBV?$vector@HV?$allocator@H@std@@@std@@0@Z) referenced in function "public: int __clrcall MathCore_CLI_namespace::MathCore_CLI::computeMulPlusVals(class System::Collections::Generic::List ^,class System::Collections::Generic::List ^)" (?computeMulPlusVals@MathCore_CLI@MathCore_CLI_namespace@@$$FQE$AAMHPE$AAV?$List@H@Generic@Collections@System@@0@Z)    EngineLib_CLI   C:\Aleksey\TestDeleteIt\Engine_CLI\MathCore_CLI.obj 1

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @Sergey_73 что запихнуть?

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/3af242aa-8c36-4307-98a6-752301c37025/how-to-pass-genericlist-to-function-in-clic-?forum=vclanguage

Comment: Помимо нормальных способов в C# ещё есть `__argList`

Comment: Так как C++/CLI - _управляемый_ язык, то он свободно может обмениваться любыми _управляемыми_ данными с C#. И как я понял, это уже сделано. Проблема в том, как трансформировать `List<T>` в `vector<T>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понял, вы уже сделали передачу списка из C# в C++/CLI.

Осталось сделать трансформацию из `List<T>` в `vector<T>`.

Имеем:

```
using namespace System::Collections::Generic;

List<int>^ list
```

Просто создаём экземпляр вектора и в цикле добавляем в него элементы:

```
std::vector<int>* vec = new std::vector<int>();

for each(int n in list) {
    vec->push_back(n);
}
```

Можно сразу создать вектор нужной длины, чтобы не было переалокаций:

```
auto vec = new std::vector<int>(list->Count);

for (int i = 0; i < list->Count; i++) {
    vec->at(i) = list[i];
}
```

Или суть вопроса в том, как избежать лишних копирований?

Comment: я понял как нужно, спасибо! Теперь только не могу понять, почему получаю ошибку компиляции. Добавил в вопрос. Есть предположения? Я так понимаю, что метод из C++ хочет получить ссылку, а я ему пытаюсь передать другой тип... Как можно исправить?

Answer (score -1):

Я нашел более оптимизированое решение

```
int MathCore_CLI::computeMulPlusVals(array<int>^ arr_first, array<int>^ arr_second)
{
    auto vec_first = std::vector<int>(arr_first->Length);
    cli::pin_ptr<int> pPinnedFirst = &arr_first[0];
    memcpy(vec_first.data(), pPinnedFirst, arr_first->Length * sizeof(int));

    auto vec_second = std::vector<int>(arr_second->Length);
    cli::pin_ptr<int> pPinnedSecond = &arr_second[0];
    memcpy(vec_second.data(), pPinnedSecond, arr_second->Length * sizeof(int));

    return m_pMathCore->computeMulPlusVals(vec_first, vec_second);
}
```

по шагам

1) нужно создать вектор
2) захватить его в памяти(чтоб в случае чего сслыки не поменялись)
3) скопировать данные

Это будет намного быстрее по производительности